# ibm inforsphere cdc open source solution

Tags: open-source, cdc, ibm-infosphere

IBM Infosphere CDC is great product to replicate data from different source and target. It is stable and user friendly. Whereas our customer want to do a benchmark of IBM Infosphere CDC with other opensourced products in the similar way. Did you have any experience in CDC? If yes, would you please let me know if there are any similar opensourced product which can be applied in small size of company?

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 0):

I worked with IBM Infosphere CDC for a long time. I'm unaware of an open source alternative. I don't believe that there's anything similar that doesn't have a licensing fee. I would say the only real competitor is Oracle Golden Gate.